# Prefill select box from jSON

Tags: jquery, json, select

JSON is

```
[["AF","Afghanistan"],["ZA","Afrique du Sud"],["AL","Albanie"]]
```

How I got it to a select box. I tried this but no luck.

```
$.getJSON('circuitCreation/countryList' + '?' + Math.round(new Date().getTime()),
    {}, function(j){
            var options = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].[0] + '">' + j[i].[1] + '</option>';
            }
            ('#select_country').html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the periods out of the for loop for accessing J.

`options += '<option value="' + j[i][0] + '">' + j[i][1] + '</option>';`

The `.` notation is for accessing object attributes and functions, but you have arrays instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I almost smash my head against the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me if you change j[i].[0]  to j[i][0] and j[i].[1] to j[i][1]